# How can i rollback jdbc template transaction?

Tags: jdbc, transactions, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions, rollback

I have 2 methods inside 1 (check getFullDataForPprs method)
this is main union service:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService {

    private final PprService pprService;
    private final ServiceService serviceService;
    private final ContactService contactService;
    private final PprDtoService pprDtoService;
    private final RabbitMQProducerService rabbitMQProducerService;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void getPprsAndWritingThemIntoSenderDB() {
        List<PprRdb> pprsFromRdb = pprService.getPprsFromRdb();
        pprService.checkAndSetErrorWorkTimeStatusIfPprIsNotActual(pprsFromRdb);
        pprService.writeOurPprsInSender(pprsFromRdb);
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void getFullDataForPprs() {
        List<ServiceRdb> services = serviceService.getServicesAndWritingThemIntoSenderDB();
        contactService.getContactsAndWritingThemIntoSenderDB(services);
    }
```

and 2 subservices like this:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceServiceImpl implements ServiceService {
    private final RdbServiceRepository rdbServiceRepository;
    private final SenderServiceRepository senderServiceRepository;
    private final SenderPprRepository senderPprRepository;
    private final PprService pprService;

    @Override
    public List<ServiceRdb> getServices(List<PprRdb> newAndActualPprs) {
        List<Long> objectIdsForFindingServices = newAndActualPprs.stream().map(PprRdb::getObjectIdPpr).toList();
        return rdbServiceRepository.getServicesFromRdbByObjectIdPprsInSender(objectIdsForFindingServices);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public List<ServiceRdb> getServicesAndWritingThemIntoSenderDB() {
        List<ServiceRdb> servicesFromRdbForActualPprs;
        List<PprRdb> newAndActualPprs = pprService.getPprsFromSenderWithStatus(PprStatus.NEW_STATUS.toString());
        servicesFromRdbForActualPprs = getServices(newAndActualPprs);
        addStringAddressesToServices(servicesFromRdbForActualPprs);
        addToServicesIdPpr(servicesFromRdbForActualPprs);
        pprService.changePprStatusForNotService(newAndActualPprs, servicesFromRdbForActualPprs);
        writeServicesIntoSender(servicesFromRdbForActualPprs);
        return servicesFromRdbForActualPprs;
    }
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    private final RdbContactRepository rdbContactRepository;
    private final SenderContactRepository senderContactRepository;
    private final PprService pprService;


    @Override
    public void getContactsAndWritingThemIntoSenderDB(List<ServiceRdb> servicesFromRdbForActualPprs) {
        List<Long> objectIdsContractFromServicesInSender = servicesFromRdbForActualPprs.stream().map(ServiceRdb::getObjectIdContract).toList();
        List<ContactRdb> contactsFromSenderWithoutEmails = getContactsFromSenderWithoutEmails(objectIdsContractFromServicesInSender);
        List<ContactRdb> contactsWithEmails = getContactsWithEmails(contactsFromSenderWithoutEmails);
        writeContactsWithEmailsInSender(contactsWithEmails);
        pprService.changePprStatusForDataReceived(servicesFromRdbForActualPprs);
    }
```

and of corse 2 repositories:

```java
@Repository
public class SenderServiceRepository {
    private final String GET_OBJECT_ID_CONTRACT_FROM_SERVICES = FileResourceUtils.getFileFromResourceAsStream("sql/get_object_id_contract_from_services.sql");

    private final String INSERT_SERVICES_INTO_PPR_BSS_SERVICE = FileResourceUtils.getFileFromResourceAsStream("sql/services/insert_services_into_ppr_bss_service.sql");

    private final JdbcTemplate senderJdbcTemplate;


    public SenderServiceRepository(@Qualifier("SenderJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate senderJdbcTemplate) {
        this.senderJdbcTemplate = senderJdbcTemplate;
    }


    public void writingServicesIntoPprBssService(List<ServiceRdb> fullServices) {
        senderJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT_SERVICES_INTO_PPR_BSS_SERVICE, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(@NotNull PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                ps.setLong(1, fullServices.get(i).getIdPprBss());
                ps.setLong(2, fullServices.get(i).getObjectIdClient());
                ps.setString(3, fullServices.get(i).getClientName());
                ps.setLong(4, fullServices.get(i).getObjectIdContract());
                ps.setString(5, fullServices.get(i).getContractName());
                ps.setLong(6, fullServices.get(i).getObjectIdLocation());
                ps.setLong(7, fullServices.get(i).getAddressId());
                ps.setString(8, fullServices.get(i).getServiceId());
                ps.setLong(9, fullServices.get(i).getObjectIdService());
                ps.setString(10, fullServices.get(i).getAddress());
                ps.setLong(11, fullServices.get(i).getObjectIdPpr());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return fullServices.size();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

```java
@Repository
public class SenderContactRepository {

    private final JdbcTemplate senderJdbcTemplate;
    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;


    public SenderContactRepository(@Qualifier("SenderJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate senderJdbcTemplate,
                               @Qualifier("namedParameterJdbcTemplateSender") NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
        this.senderJdbcTemplate = senderJdbcTemplate;
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }
   public void writeContactsWithEmails(List<ContactRdb> emailsFromRdbForContacts) {
        senderJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT_CONTACTS_INTO_PPR_BSS_CONTACT, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(@NotNull PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                ps.setLong(1, emailsFromRdbForContacts.get(i).getIdPprBss());
                ps.setLong(2, emailsFromRdbForContacts.get(i).getObjectIdContract());
                ps.setLong(3, emailsFromRdbForContacts.get(i).getObjectIdPpr());
                ps.setLong(4, emailsFromRdbForContacts.get(i).getContactId());
                ps.setString(5, emailsFromRdbForContacts.get(i).getEmail());
                ps.setBoolean(6, emailsFromRdbForContacts.get(i).isVip());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return emailsFromRdbForContacts.size();
            }
        });
    }
```

how do I make a transaction for recording services roll back if an exception crashes between the first and second method in the main getFullDataForPprs method?

i have tried every combination of @transactional, also i got a message from debug logger that my transaction is rollbacked, but anyway it is not. whyyyy???? I'm using spring-boot, also i have tried auto-commit false in yaml, but it still not works